# why does my print statement output all these extra parentheses in the output console

Tags: swift, xcode

I am in the swift playground and in my code I have no idea why the output of my print statements  are being outputted with these extra parentheses on separate lines as shown down below.
Code:

```
import UIKit

class Pets {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
    func feed () {
        print ("\(name) has eaten.")
    }
    func clean () {
        print ("\(name) has bathed.")
    }
    func play () {
        print ("\(name) enjoyed playing.")
    }
    func sleep () {
        print ("\(name) went to sleep.")
    }
    func old () {
        print ("\(name) is \(age) years old")
    }
    func test() {print("hi")
        
    }
}
var pet = Pets()

pet.name = "cat"
pet.age = 15

print(pet.test())
print(pet.old())
print(pet.feed())
print(pet.clean())
print(pet.play())
print(pet.sleep())
```

And output:

```
hi
()
cat is 15 years old
()
cat has eaten.
()
cat has bathed.
()
cat enjoyed playing.
()
cat went to sleep.
()
(Function)
cat has bathed.
```

Comment: You’re also printing the print() function- you’re printing a function that prints something… you may have a function that returns a string like that func test() -> String { return “hi” } and then when you’ll print it it will look just fine

Comment: just write pet.test() remove print from all above lines

Answer (score -1):

FIRST OPTION:

In the functions in the Pets.swift Model, you specified that it should print already

so you should not say

```
print(pet.test())
print(pet.old())
print(pet.feed())
print(pet.clean())
print(pet.play())
print(pet.sleep())
```

instead just say

```
pet.test
pet.old
pet.feed
pet.clean
pet.play
pet.sleep
```

ALTERNATIVELY:

you can setup your model for Pets.swift file like this:

```
class Pets {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    
    init(name: String, age: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

then you can print like this:

```
let cat = Pets(name: "cat", age: 15) 

print("\(name) has eaten.")
print("\(name) has bathed.")
print("\(name) enjoyed playing.")
print("\(name) went to sleep.")
print("\(name) is \(age) years old")
print("hi")
```